# what is benefit of $(e).attr(name,value) vs e.setAttribute(name,value)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Case: `e` is of type `HtmlElement` and not `css selector`

I am talking about any attribute, not just standard allowed ones, like `atom-type` or `data-atom-type`, whatever may be the name, will it work without jQuery?

I suspect `$(e).attr(name,value)` is too slow, **first of all it is creating an entire jQuery object** `($(e) !== $(e) // two objects are not same)` (jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-vs-native-setattribute/28) and then it invokes certain checks and then sets value, which most browsers easily support `e.setAttribute`.

Is there any problem replacing `$(e).attr(name,value)` to `e.setAttribute(name,value)`?

IE8 supports `setAttribute` as per MSDN documentation. Is there any mobile browser or any browser which will not support it?

Eventually I want to improve performance of my JavaScript framework, initially we used jQuery extensively for its cross browser DOM features.

We have now understood that unless you are using `css selector`, most functions such as `attr,val,text` are better called with their direct DOM counter part when you have instance of `HtmlElement`.

Comment: it's look to me that second one will not work in IE8 as $(obj).trim() not work.

Comment: @Anirugu can you give me some example?

Comment: @Anirugu: `setAttribute` works in IE8. There are a couple of bugs, but it *mostly* works.

Comment: @AkashKava Actually trying $("input").val().trim() was broken in old IE version. The correct code for old IE is $.trim("val");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I suspect `$(e).attr(name,value)` is too slow, first of all it is creating an entire jQuery object and then it invokes certain checks and then sets value, which most browsers easily support `e.setAttribute`.

If you [measure it](http://jsperf.com), you'll find that the difference in performance is large-ish in relative terms, but ***miniscule*** in absolute terms, and it's absolute terms we normally care about. It just doesn't matter in 99.999999% of cases. If you run into a *specific* performance problem, and trace it to using jQuery, *then* consider optimizing at that point.

> what is benefit of `$(e).attr(name,value)` vs `e.setAttribute(name,value)`?

In the specific case you mention, where `e` is an `HTMLElement`, there are only a couple of benefits:

- There are a couple of IE-specific bugs in `setAttribute` that jQuery works around for you
- There are some "attributes" people set when they really should be setting a property, for instance `checked` or `disabled`; jQuery maps those (this is mostly a legacy feature these days, as people should be using `prop`)
- It does some pre-processing on boolean values for you, letting you use `$(e).attr("checked", true)` when `true` really should be `"checked"`

> IE8 supports setAttribute as per MSDN documentation. Is there any mobile browser or any browser which will not support it?

All browsers support `setAttribute`. As I mention earlier, various versions of IE have had various bugs in it, but it's there and mostly works.

Comment: You are right for most part but I have written a framework, http://github.com/neurospeech/atoms.js and we are using it to create nearly 1000 to 5000 HtmlElements on one page, 10 milliseconds faster makes it 10 seconds faster for our application. We did replace $(e).text with simple JS code. I will be replacing jQuery with our custom script that will not instantiate new object. Your answer is helpful to create test cases I needed.

Comment: I added jsPerf, and it is not 99.99999%, there is a huge difference,

Comment: @AkashKava: Read the answer again: *"the difference in performance is large-ish in relative terms, but miniscule in absolute terms"* Again:  It just doesn't matter in 99.999999% of cases. In the very rare cases where it matters (e.g., you're doing something in a tight loop or something), then you optimize.